# I started and worked on a new branch, and now I want to discard it, go back to the master, and pretend the branch never happened. How can I do this?

Tags: git, github

I started a branch for a new feature, but after working on it (and making several commits), I decided that I don't like it and I want to go back to the master, remove the feature branch, and start a new one. What steps should I take to get back to the last commit on the master branch and pretend the feature branch never happened?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git checkout -f master
git branch -D MyFeatureBranch
```

If you want to create a new feature branch from latest master:

```
git pull origin master
git checkout -b MyFeatureBranch2
```

Answer (score 0):

First checkout the master branch, then when on the master branch do a `git branch` with the `-d` flag.

```
> git checkout master
> git branch -D mybranch
```

Comment: `-d` will not delete branch if it is not fully merged to master in this case, should use `-D`